# I cannot resolve the path from Storyboard.TargetProperty in my WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-animation

In my WPF application I have an animation of a certain element. The element to be animated looks like this.

```xml
    <Path x:Name="theX" StrokeThickness="7" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup>
                <LineGeometry StartPoint="4, 4" EndPoint="60, 60"/>
                <LineGeometry StartPoint="4, 60" EndPoint="60, 4"/>
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

The color of the `LineGeometry` elements should be animated, but I don't know how the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` path is resolved. In this case the `GeometryGroup` element causes problems. How is the `GeometryGroup` element accommodated in the path of the `Storyboard.TargetProperty`, see the three "???".

I've already tried the following:
`...).GeometryGroup.(...`  `...).(GeometryGroup.Children).(...`  `...).GeometryCollection.(...` ... also i've tried that `(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`

```xml
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:1" Duration="0:0:1"
                                                              Storyboard.TargetName="theX"
                                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).???.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                              FillBehavior="Stop">
                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#333333" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#6AFF00" KeyTime="0:0:0.2"/>
                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#6AFF00" KeyTime="0:0:0.5"/>
                <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#333333" KeyTime="0:0:0.9"/>
     </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

The Geometry-elements are part of a `DataTemplat` of an `ItemsControl` with data binding. And I get an exception on the .NET property linked via data binding.

[image]

The translation of the exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: "Not all property references in property path" (0) .GeometryGroup. (1) "can be resolved. Make sure that suitable objects support the properties."

In the application there is a similar element, an `EllipseGeometry`, in which the animation works in this way. The difference is the `GeometryGroup` element.

```xml
<Path x:Name="theO" StrokeThickness="6" Stroke="Transparent">
    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="25, 25" RadiusX="22" RadiusY="22"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>


<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:1" Duration="0:0:1"
                                                              Storyboard.TargetName="theO"
                                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                              FillBehavior="Stop">
                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#333333" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#FF4F00" KeyTime="0:0:0.2"/>
                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#FF4F00" KeyTime="0:0:0.5"/>
                <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#333333" KeyTime="0:0:0.9"/>
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Look at your animation that works. You're working with the path. This has fill and stroke which are brushes. At first glance, removing those questionmarks looks like it might work.

Comment: @Andy thanks for your comment, but that doesn't work.  I had already tried that when I wrote the animation.  I will try to add it to the question.

Comment: `(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)` - This path will work if the Path.Stroke property contains an unfrozen SolidColorBrush instance.
According to your explanations, it is not clear what you have there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice in the working example you have a transparent brush set to the Stroke property.
But in the first example, nothing is set to this property.
Hence it is null.
And null has no properties to animate them.

You can explicitly set  SolidColorBrush instance in this property, give this instance a name, and access its Color property directly.
It will be much easier than all these casts.

Example:

```
        <Path x:Name="theX" StrokeThickness="7" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
            <Path.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="PathStroke" Color="Transparent"/>
            </Path.Stroke>
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="4, 4" EndPoint="60, 60"/>
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="4, 60" EndPoint="60, 4"/>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
```

```
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:1"
                                      Duration="0:0:1"
                                      Storyboard.TargetName="PathStroke"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                      FillBehavior="Stop">
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#333333" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#6AFF00" KeyTime="0:0:0.2"/>
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#6AFF00" KeyTime="0:0:0.5"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#333333" KeyTime="0:0:0.9"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.  I can't rate the answer yet because I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: It does not matter.
The main thing helped you.